# How do I run a downloaded repository's config in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use sunnyportal-py. Relatively new to python, I do not understand step 2 in the README:

## How to run

1. Clone or download the repository.
2. Enter the directory and run:
   `PYTHONPATH=. ./bin/sunnyportal2pvoutput --dry-run sunnyportal.config`
3. Enter the requested information and verify that the script is able to connect to Sunny Portal.
4. The information is saved in sunnyportal.config and can be edited/deleted if you misstype anything.
5. Once it works, replace --dry-run with e.g. --output to upload the last seven days output data to pvoutput or --status to upload data for the current day.
6. Add --quiet to silence the output.

Could anyone help me? I have gone into a cmd.exe in the folder I have downloaded, I don't know how to correctly write the python path in the correct location. What should I paste into the command line? Thanks!

Edit : I would like to be able to do this on Windows, do tell me if this is possible.

Comment: Maybe it is suitable for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The command at bullet 2 is to be typed at the commandline (You need to be in windows: cmd or powershell, Linux: bash, etc.. to be able to do this).

> PYTHONPATH=. ./bin/sunnyportal2pvoutput --dry-run sunnyportal.config

The first part of the command code above indicates where your program is located. Go to the specific folder via commandline (windows: cd:... ; where .. is your foldername) and type the command.

The second part is the command to be executed. Its behind the "--" dashes. The program knows what to do. In this case:

> --dry-run sunnyportal.config

running a validation/config file to see if the program code itself works; as indicated by "dry run".

In your case type at the location (while in cmd):

> "sunnyportal2pvoutput --dry-run sunnyportal.config"

or

> "sunnyportal2pvoutput.py --dry-run sunnyportal.config" (without the environment variables (python path) set).

Note: the pythonpath is an environment variable. This can be added via: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\ --> bullet Advanced System Settings --> button "environment variables". Then you can select to add it to "Variables for user "username"" or "system variables". Remember to reboot thereafter to make the change effective immediately.

Update 1 (pip install sunnyportal):

1. go to cmd.
2. type "pip search sunnyportal"

Result:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836] (c) 2019 Microsoft
> Corporation. All rights reserved.
> C:\Windows\System32>pip search
> sunnyportal
>
> sunnyportal-py (0.0.4)  - A Python client for SMA sunny portal
>
> C:\Windows\System32>

If found, then type:

"pip install sunnyportal"

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I understand a lot better now. However, I still need in help as I do not know what exactly to type is the command line so that I can config and provide my authentication details. https://github.com/erijo/sunnyportal-py is what I am trying to configure

Comment: I haven't 'installed' it, I just downloaded the ZIP from Github onto my downloads folder. In that folder, I opened a command line, however I don't know how to run the config is listed in the README file.

Comment: This means you didn't install it with pip or conda. Go via cmd to the unzipped folder and type "sunnyportal2pvoutput.py --dry-run sunnyportal.config". Or try installing with pip and type "sunnyportal2pvoutput --dry-run sunnyportal.config".

Comment: Found the answer on Reddit, thanks for your help. The answer was to paste py bin/sunnyportal2pvoutput sunnyportal.config
inside.